# Como unir arquivos em pastas, baseado em seus prefixos?

Tags: group-by, groovy

Tenho em mão milhares de arquivos que possuem prefixos comuns em seus nomes, algo como:

[Exemplo de prefixo 1]

- ABC-1.mp4
- ABC-2.mp4
- ABC-3.mp4
- [...]
- ABC-999.mp4

[Exemplo de prefixo 2]

- AAA-1.mp4
- AAA-2.mp4
- AAA-3.mp4
- [...]
- AAA-999.mp4

Porém, são milhares de arquivos e milhares de prefixos em comum. Gostaria de unir os arquivos que possuem mesmo prefixo numa mesma pasta, sendo que a pasta teria o nome do prefixo, como por exemplo:

- ABC (seria o nome da pasta)

  - ABC-1.mp4
  - ABC-2.mp4
  - ABC-3.mp4
  - [...]
  - ABC-999.mp4
- AAA (seria o nome da pasta)

  - AAA-1.mp4
  - AAA-2.mp4
  - AAA-3.mp4
  - [...]
  - AAA-999.mp4

Comment: Isso precisa ser feito em C ou a linguagem não importa? Outra dúvida, Linux ou Windows?

Comment: Qualquer linguagem, o importante é solucionar esse problema.. Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução na linguagem Groovy 2.4.4

Download do Groovy: http://www.groovy-lang.org/download.html

É preciso ter o Java instalado para o Groovy funcionar.

```
def folders = new File("/home/cantoni/Documents/Teste")
def destFolder = "/home/cantoni/Documents/Teste2/"

folders.listFiles().groupBy {it.name.substring(0,3)}.each {group ->
    def folder = new File(destFolder + group.key)
    if (!folder.exists()) new File(destFolder + group.key).mkdir()

    def files = group.value

    files.each {
        it.renameTo(folder.absolutePath + "/" + it.name)
    }
}
```

**Código explicado**

O código acima, percorre todos os arquivos que estão dentro da pasta especificada pela variável *folders*, logo em seguida, agrupa-os pelos 3 primeiros caracteres que compõe o nome.

```
folders.listFiles().groupBy {it.name.substring(0,3)}
```

O resultado do agrupamento é um map, onde a chave são os 3 primeiros caracteres e o valor são os arquivos que possuem esses 3 primeiros caracteres no nome. Exemplo:

```
AAA-123.TXT
AAC-234.TXT
AAA-553.TXT
AAC-001.TXT
CCC-987.TXT
```

O mapa ficaria assim:

```
AAA: [AAA-123.TXT,AAA-553.TXT], AAC: [AAC-234.TXT,AAC-001.TXT], CCC: [CCC-987.TXT]
```

A partir disso, cria-se a pasta (caso a mesma não exista), dentro da pasta especificada pela variável *destFolder*. O nome de cada pasta é o key do map, ou seja, os três primeiros caracteres.

```
    def folder = new File(destFolder + group.key)
    if (!folder.exists()) new File(destFolder + group.key).mkdir()
```

Criada a pasta, é hora de mover os arquivos. O *value* do map são os arquivos que compartilham da mesma chave. Assim, basta recuperá-los, percorrê-los e, para cada um, realizar o procedimento de movê-los do local atual para a pasta de destino, *destFolder*.

```
    def files = group.value

    files.each {
        it.renameTo(folder.absolutePath + "/" + it.name)
    }
```

**Atenção**

Esse código foi testado no Linux e funciona. Faça um teste com outros arquivos antes de rodá-lo com seus arquivos de produção. Precaução nunca é demais.

Comment: E se eu quiser que a chave para o agrupamento seja os caracteres antes de um hífen (-), incluindo espaços, ao invés de ser os 3 primeiros caracteres?

Comment: folders.listFiles().groupBy {it.name.substring(0,it.name.indexOf("-"))}. Note, entretanto, que isso só funcionará se existir o caracter "-" no nome do arquivo. Caso não exista, não vai rodar. Se você tiver um cenário bem padronizado, esse código, da maneira que está, ajudará. Caso exista um cenário heterogêneo, é preciso modificá-lo. Certamente, nada complicado, principalmente porque se trata de Groovy.

Comment: Poderia explicar essa linha do código? def folders = new File("/home/cantoni/Documents/Teste")

Comment: Nesta linha, estou instanciando um objeto do tipo File, passando como parametro uma pasta do meu computador, o objeto File (sua referencia na realidade), está sendo atribuída à variável folders. No seu caso (Windows), seria algo como: def folders = new File("C:\Users\thiago\PastaX").

Comment: Qual a diferença para o destFolder?

Comment: folder é a pasta de origem, aonde se encontram os arquivos que você deseja separar. destFolder é a variável que guarda a pasta de destino.